# Can't start mysql after downgrade, can't run mysql_upgrade, can't change root password

Tags: mysql

I downgraded a mysql server from 5.7.14 to 5.6.32.

After doing so, I presumed I was supposed to run mysql_upgrade, according to the instructions I came across.

However, to do so, I need to supply the root user/p, which I have. However, it doesn't appear to be accepting those when I attempt to do so:

> mysql_upgrade -u root -p
>
> Enter password:
>
> Looking for 'mysql' as: mysql
>
> Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: mysqlcheck
>
> Error: Failed while fetching Server version! Could be due to unauthorized access.
>
> FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed

So I attempted to reset the password, by creating an init file with something like:
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('abcd1234');
and then calling it with mysqld_safe --init-file=/home/root/mysql-init &

But this doesn't seem to work, presumably because mysql can't startup correctly and throws an error.

```
0802 12:50:45 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql

2016-08-02 12:50:46 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is 

2016-08-02 12:50:46 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.6.32) starting as process 2635 ...

2016-08-02 12:50:46 2635 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.

/usr/sbin/mysqld: Unknown storage engine 'InnoDB'

2016-08-02 12:50:46 2635 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.

2016-08-02 12:50:46 2635 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages

2016-08-02 12:50:46 2635 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled

2016-08-02 12:50:46 2635 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins

2016-08-02 12:50:46 2635 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used

2016-08-02 12:50:46 2635 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3

2016-08-02 12:50:46 2635 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO

2016-08-02 12:50:46 2635 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions

2016-08-02 12:50:46 2635 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M

2016-08-02 12:50:46 2635 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool

2016-08-02 12:50:46 2635 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.

2016-08-02 12:50:46 2635 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 2512357 and 

2512357 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 2512396 in $

2016-08-02 12:50:46 2635 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!

2016-08-02 12:50:46 2635 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.

2016-08-02 12:50:46 2635 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...

2016-08-02 12:50:46 2635 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages

2016-08-02 12:50:46 2635 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...

InnoDB: wrong number of columns in SYS_INDEXES record

InnoDB: wrong number of columns in SYS_INDEXES record

InnoDB: wrong number of columns in SYS_INDEXES record

InnoDB: wrong number of columns in SYS_INDEXES record

InnoDB: wrong number of columns in SYS_INDEXES record
17:50:46 UTC - mysqld got signal 11 ;
```

This would seem to leave me in a loop where I can't run mysql_upgrade to upgrade the db, and yet I can't successfully reset the root password (Although I'm 99.9% sure I've got the correct root password, it just doesn't appear to be accepting it.)

Stack trace..

```
Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...

stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x40000

/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x35)[0x8e2375]

/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x494)[0x666da4]

/lib64/libpthread.so.0[0x398620f790]

/usr/sbin/mysqld[0xac1017]

/usr/sbin/mysqld[0xac25fd]

/usr/sbin/mysqld[0xa3de77]

/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x9822dd]

/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z24ha_initialize_handlertonP13st_plugin_int+0x48)[0x5aa958]

/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x6f01e1]

/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z11plugin_initPiPPci+0xbb6)[0x6f4046]

/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x59ce38]

/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z11mysqld_mainiPPc+0x425)[0x5a2055]

/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd)[0x3985e1ed5d]

/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x593ba5]
```

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Signal 11 is a segfault... That would mean that you have some sort of memory access violation. Maybe a linkage issue, wrongly resolved package dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

The instructions you came across were dead wrong. The only instructions that matter are those [from MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/downgrading.html):

> Supported downgrade methods include:
>
> *In-place Downgrade*: Involves shutting down the new MySQL version, replacing the new MySQL binaries or packages with the old ones, and restarting the old MySQL version on the existing data directory. **In-place downgrades are supported for downgrades between GA versions within the same release series.** For example, in-place downgrades are supported for downgrades from 5.7.10 to 5.7.9.
>
> *Logical Downgrade*: Involves using [`mysqldump`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html) to dump all tables from the new MySQL version, and then loading the dump file into the old MySQL version. **Logical downgrades are supported for downgrades between GA versions within the same release series and for downgrades between release levels.** For example, logical downgrades are supported for downgrades from 5.7.10 to 5.7.9 and for downgrades from 5.7 to 5.6.
>
> For procedures, see [Performing an In-place Downgrade](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/downgrading.html#downgrade-procedure-inplace), and [Performing a Logical Downgrade](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/downgrading.html#downgrade-procedure-logical).

Note my bolding. The only supported option you had was to use `mysqldump` to pull a copy of the database and then import it to the older version. Hopefully you've got some backups!

Comment: Yeah, that's where I got the instructions from.

However, I was trying to do an in-place downgrade rather than a logical downgrade.

I was able to restore the 5.7.14 components, and try the actions for the logical downgrade.

However, this also did not work, because of this change: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/136320/got-error-while-reverting-mysql-5-7-to-mysql-5-6

Ultimately, I had to nuke the mysql.user table after downgrading, restoring, starting with skip tables, and then recreate the table, readd users, and regrant permissions. It was a fun day.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do an in-place downgrade rather than a logical downgrade.

I was able to restore the 5.7.14 components, and try the actions for the logical downgrade.

However, this also did not work, because of [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/136320/got-error-while-reverting-mysql-5-7-to-mysql-5-6) change to the user table structure. Ultimately, I had to nuke the mysql.user table after downgrading, restoring, starting the service with skip-grant-tables option, and then recreate the table, re-add my users, and re-grant permissions. It was a fun day.